# Cant make different carousels work properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my page, I have multiple games one below the other.
Each game has a distinct carousel.
The problem is that only the first one works as expected.
All the other carousels when the next or previous button is pressed they change the images of the first carousel. They still auto slide though.
I want a way to make each one of the carousels to work distinctly.

I tried to use an i = 0 for the ids to make them work distinctly but that didnt work as expected since none of them worked.

Also, the other issue that I am facing is that when the carousel button is pressed this black background appears carousel-control.

[image]

Any thoughts?

**index.html.erb** 
is inside a loop

**here is my code**

```
            <div id="carouselId" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style = "width:450px; height: 250px; ">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#carouselId" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselId" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselId" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

              <div class="item active">
                  <%=image_tag "#{@stadio.stadium_name}/1.jpg" %>
              </div>

              <div class="item">
                  <%=image_tag "#{@stadio.stadium_name}/2.jpg" %>  
              </div>

              <div class="item">
                  <%= image_tag "#{@stadio.stadium_name}/3.jpg" %>
              </div>

            </div>


            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carouselId" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true" ></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carouselId" data-slide="next">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true" ></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>   
         </div>
```

Comment: You need to have unique id's for each carousel

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap 4, use     `<div class="carousel-item">`

Comment: @VipulSharma  i am using bootstrap-sass

Comment: @Dustin only the id? or also the hrefs?

Comment: The id's and the href's both need to be updated.

Comment: @VipulSharma yes but how can i do that? Is there a way to put a variable there?

Comment: Since you said that clicking next always updates first carousel, the href in the line below should have the problem. Update this line in every carousel with the id of the respective carousel    `<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carouselId" data-slide="prev">`  If still not working then post your another carousel too.

Comment: @VipulSharma this carousel is inside a loop so i need a way to make each id distinct with something so that they are generated from the for loop

Comment: Could you post another carousel?

Comment: I posted an example of what multiple stacked carousels should look like, pay attention to the id's and data-target.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="row1">
    <h1>400x400</h1>
    <div class="bd-example">
      <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://placebear.com/400/400" alt="400x400" />
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>400x400</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/400/400" alt="400x400" />
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>400x400</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://placekitten.com/g/400/400" alt="400x400" />
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>400x400</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="row2">
    <div class="bd-example">
      <h1>600x600</h1>
      <div id="carouselExampleCaptions2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions2" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions2" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://placebear.com/600/600" alt="600x600" />
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>600x600</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/600/600" alt="600x600" />
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>600x600</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://placekitten.com/g/600/600" alt="600x600" />
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>600x600</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions2" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="row3">
    <h1>250x250</h1>
    <div class="bd-example">
      <div id="carouselExampleCaptions3" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions3" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions3" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions3" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://placebear.com/250/250" alt="250x250" />
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>250x250</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/250/250" alt="250x250" />
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>250x250</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://placekitten.com/g/250/250" alt="250x250" />
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>250x250</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions3" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions3" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok i got it! So every id should be unique! Is there a way to do this with a variable ? I mean like  carouselId = 0 and then in the code to make it carouselId += 1? would that work? Because i want to use this in a loop.

Comment: Are you looking to dynamically call different carousels depending on.....or are you looking to loop through a collection and show the results on the carousel